# Mouse over Selenium Webdrive 2 Java

Tags: java, selenium, mouse

I am working on a public site.  preview.harriscounty.org
I am trying to mouse over ANY one of the many markers in the right pane, but I am not having success.

When you mouse over, a small popup occurs, and a "More Information" link is displayed.  My goal is to click on that through mouse actions.

Below, I pasted code based on my research.  I implemented in two different ways, but I am not getting any results.  See if you can help crack this case.  Much appreciated.  BTW, There is a function called `loadAll` in the code, which simply selects All the markers, because I don't know which one I am selecting (I'm selecting any one of them).  Just use the function pasted as-is.  This avoids trying to mouse over an invisible marker (by first calling `loadAll`).  I also included Sleep method code, although noteworthy is that `Sleep(2);` is the same thing as `Thread.sleep(2000);`

STATIC MAIN METHOD CODE (EXECUTION STARTS HERE):

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebDriver driver;
driver.get("http://preview.harriscountyfws.org/");

//Select All Sites Agencies (followed by Close button):
loadAll(driver);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
            "Locating and mousing over to a Rainmarker\n\n    ");

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("rainMarker"));

Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();
Sleep(5);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Did you see anything?\n\n    ");

Locatable hoverItem = (Locatable) element;
Mouse mouse = ((HasInputDevices) driver).getMouse();
mouse.mouseMove(hoverItem.getCoordinates());
Sleep(5);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Did you see anything?\n\n    ");




public static void loadAll(WebDriver driver) {
    WebElement we, listbox_element;
    we = driver.findElement(
            By.xpath("//div[@id='searchDiv']//span[@aria-owns='ddlRegion_listbox']//span[@class='k-select']"));
    we.click();

    new WebDriverWait(driver, 3, 100).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
            By.id("regionSelectPopup")));

    listbox_element= driver.findElement(
            By.xpath("//div[@id='regionSelectPopup']//label[.='ALL']/preceding-sibling::input[@type='checkbox']"));

    listbox_element.click();
    we = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"regionSelectPopup\"]/div[2]/input"));  // CLOSE BUTTON
    we.click();
    Sleep(1);
}


public static void Sleep(int i)
{
    try
    {
        if (i<100)
        Thread.sleep(i * 1000);
        else Thread.sleep(i);
    }catch(InterruptedException ie)
    {
        //Log message if required.
        System.out.println("Unexpected error in sleep method.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there,  I opened the website but not sure to what you are referring to as 'markers on the right pane' can you give us a screenshot perhaps? If you just need to locate ( or mouse over) to any of the radio buttons I can help you ( I think)..

Comment: when you visit http://preview.harriscountyfws.org/   you will see little red rectangle boxes on the right pane.  Each rectangle box will have a different number (or sometimes just 0.0).  This tells you the rainfall at any given point.  I just want to mouse over one of these red-edged boxes.  Then, I want to click on the "More information" link that pops up when you mouse over.

Comment: Ok got it, I entered the address wrongly, sorry my bad but it was missing fws on the original post..Bear with me.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I selected the option 'City of Sugar Land' only to reduce number of markers. First piece of code between dashed lines, first line selects all options and then deselects all options. Then chooses the required options. Include at your own judgement.

```
--------------------------------------

String location = "City of Sugar Land";
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='regionSelectPopup']//label[.='ALL']/preceding-sibling::input[@type='checkbox']")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='regionSelectPopup']//label[.='ALL']/preceding-sibling::input[@type='checkbox']")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='regionSelectPopup']//label[.='"+ location +"']/preceding-sibling::input[@type='checkbox']")).click();
    -----------------------------------
```

> Below does the mouse over etc etc. Set the variable below to whatever value you want.

```
String markerValue = "1.32";

        WebElement rainMarker = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='mapDiv']/div/div/div/div[not(contains(@style,'display'))]"
                + "//a[@class='MapPushpinBase']/div[@class='rainMarker'][.='"+ markerValue +"']"));

        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.moveToElement(rainMarker).perform();

        new WebDriverWait(driver, 3, 100).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(rainMarker));

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='infoBox'][contains(@style,'visibility: visible')]/a")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks Grasshopper.  I was hoping for a better answer because we aren't guaranteed that the rainfall is going to be 1.32 all the time.  I could get input from the user while testing.  And stuff that into the search.  I will keep this question as unanswered for now to see I get any better answers.  Last resort, I can do it this way (get input from user, and stuff into a search for 1.32).  BTW, I still haven't tried out the code yet.  In the process of confirming if it works or not, but hoping for a better answer.

Comment: 1.32 was a proof of concept value to figure out cleanly what can work. What r u looking for? All the markers need to be clicked for 'More Information' or you looking for a specific marker? If you looking for a specific marker how do you identify it? Seems there is an unique gage id with some kind of location desc.

Comment: no, any marker.  we are just validating clickability from map into marker.  it can be any marker, not the one with 1.32 inches of rain.  but searching for 1.32 can cause problem because the number might vary.  there may be no marker with 1.32 when I run it tomorrow.

Comment: Updated the code in answer. I put in the variable for marker value which you can change. If you want to change city a variable is there too. Got no idea how you plan to run this code through eclipse directly or junit etc. Take note that you do not touch or move the mouse when you run this test. Best of luck!!

Comment: Grasshopper, the code doesn't work, even when 1.32 is hardcoded like that.  that would have been an ok option (getting input from user and stuffing in 1.32 based on user typing in the "1.32").....  Actually, it can be any rain marker.  Just need to get into one of them.  The code doesn't work.

Comment: It works perfectly at my end. I am using firefox 46 with selenium 2.52 as well as chrome 52.

Comment: 1.32 is not even in Sugarland.  At any rate, excluding that part of the logic, I get NoSuchElementException..... I am using 2.53 selenium.  The rest is the same....  Kind of scary to think all your work might go down the hole when you upgrade!

Comment: There is 1.32 in the preview site. Are you running on the main site which does not have 1.32. Make the variable 3.00, just checked there is one in the preview site. What is the version of your firefox? Which OS? I am on windows 8.1

Comment: 1.32 is there in the Preview site, which I am running, but your code filters on Sugar land.  So therefore, 1.32 is not there (it would become invisible as soon as you filter on Sugar Land).   Now, what I did, I just didn't apply that code.  I did the other statements.  I am running 46 Chrome, 2.53 Selenium, Windows 7 PC.

Comment: Upgraded to selenium 2.53.1. Commented the city selection part. I tried with 1.12. And it worked on FF46. As there so many markers in a bunch mouse actions are overlapping. Try 1.12 at your end.

Comment: Add a sleep of 2-3 secs before this line in case of element not found errors - String markerValue... Works for me on chrome too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121291/discussion-between-sir-fartsalot-and-grasshopper).

Comment: we had lengthy chat on this.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Okay this xpath below will give you all the elements so you can try and iterate trough them if you want (probably via an array list).

```
//div[@id='mapDivContainer']//div[@class='rainMarker']
```

Alternatively, if you want to perform the hover then click action this needs to happen in 2 steps:

```
Actions gotoElement= new Actions(driver);
hoverElement= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='mapDivContainer']//div[@class='rainMarker']")
gotoElement.moveToElement(hoverElement).perform();
```

And then click on the info box:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='//div[@id='mapDivContainer']//div[@id='infoBox']")
gotoElement.moveToElement(clickInfoBox).click().perform();
```

Comment: there were syntax problems in your code which I was able to fix, but nope, it didn't work.  NoSuchElementException.